# How do you ensure type-safety when instantiating objects via JPQL queries?

Tags: java, jpa, design-patterns

I'll ask it straight away, can you instantiate objects using a builder in JPQL queries? For example, this query

```java
TypedQuery<QuestionCommentResponseDto> query = entityManager.createQuery("""
                            SELECT new stack.overflow.model.dto.response.QuestionCommentResponseDto (
                            qc.id, q.id, qc.createdDate, qc.modifiedDate, qc.text
                            ) FROM QuestionComment qc JOIN qc.question q
                            WHERE qc.id = :id
                        """, QuestionCommentResponseDto.class)
                .setParameter("id", id);
```

is error-prone. You can easily accidentally type `questionId` (`q.id`) first and `QuestionCommentResponseDto`'s `id` (`qc.id`) second (not the other way around), and the program will silently do the wrong thing. If I could use a builder, it would be safer, but **can I actually do it in JPQL queries? If not, how else do I ensure type-safety in such scenarios?** Note `QuestionCommentResponseDto` is not an `@Entity`

What Sage (a chat bot) has to say:

> No, unfortunately you cannot use a builder to instantiate objects in JPA queries.
>
> JPA's JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language) provides the SELECT NEW syntax that allows you to create instances of non-entity classes (such as QuestionCommentResponseDto) using a constructor with arguments. However, JPQL does not support the use of builders to create instances of non-entity classes.
>
> The reason for this is that JPQL is a query language that maps to SQL, and SQL does not support the use of builders. SQL only supports the use of constructors with arguments to create instances of result set objects.

Here's an interesting example from [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria). It covers Criteria API, a supposedly type-safe alternative to JPQL queries

```java
public class PersonWrapper {

    private final Long id;

    private final String nickName;

    public PersonWrapper(Long id, String nickName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }
}


CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<PersonWrapper> criteria = builder.createQuery(PersonWrapper.class);
Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);

Path<Long> idPath = root.get(Person_.id);
Path<String> nickNamePath = root.get(Person_.nickName);

criteria.select(builder.construct(PersonWrapper.class, idPath, nickNamePath));

/*
↑ does it call the canonical constructor? then it's not that type-safe. 
if it doesn't, how does it associate personWrapper.id with person.id, etc.?
by names?
*/

criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get(Person_.name), "John Doe"));

List<PersonWrapper> wrappers = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

Do you agree that my query can be safely replaced with Criteria code?